# Querying multiple Data Sources together

Tags: sql, node.js, spring, neo4j, graphql

We have multiple data sources, which have more than a billion records in different tables, most of them are Oracle SQL data sources along with a few NoSQL solutions. The primary fields have different names in different sources. SQL Queries can only join tables in a particular data source. Writing REST API's and stitching data in each API is not possible as our queries are dynamic and might change over time.

How can we tackle this problem, Can GraphQL servers help us stitch multiple data sources and query each with different conditions?

What we seek is a query language that can query across data sources, stitch them together based on certain conditions like join queries and return us the resultset.

```
Table 1(Oracle SQL server 1):-

|username | age | tenant |
 abc        56    US
 xyz        32    IN



Table 2 (Oracle SQL server 2):-

|userid | config | duration |
 abc     {..json.}    2100s

the query could be like:- 
select * from table1, table2 where table1.userid=table2.username and duration>2000s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK dblink1 
   CONNECT TO user1 IDENTIFIED BY password1 USING 'connect1';

CREATE DATABASE LINK dblink2 
   CONNECT TO user2 IDENTIFIED BY password2 USING 'connect2';

select * from table1@dblink1 AS t1, table2@dblink2 AS t2 where t1.userid=t2.userid and t2.duration > 2000;
```

Note: DB Link should be created once, select could be repeated many times.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK has many options, but I hope the idea helps.
```

Comment: That'll work only with SQL databases, not NoSql database.

Comment: In your questions both tables are Oracle SQL Server: Table 1(Oracle SQL server 1)
Table 2 (Oracle SQL server 2).

Comment: That's just an example but I've mentioned we've got Oracle SQL and a few NoSql databases. I'll edit the example to add a Mongo collection too